# shutdown now extremely slow due to service with DefaultDependencies=no

Tags: systemd, embedded

I have an embedded Linux system that takes a really long time to shutdown when a specific service that I've made is running. It needs  to start running as soon as possible thats why it has the DefaultDependencies=no option set.

When I run

```bash
systemctl stop myService
```

It works as expected, the service instantly stops.

However when I run

```bash
shutdown now
```

I can see that the service keeps running (LEDs keep changing)
The executable that the service runs has a signal handler for SIGTERM and SIGINT

It also stops nicely if I manually run the executable and press ctrl+c to send a SIGINT

I can't get any good log info from journalctl unfortunately.

Does anyone know how this can happen?

Does a shutdown not trigger a systemctl stop to all services?

Do I need to specify something else to get it to shutdown properly instead?

edit: as requested the service

```
### My service###

[Unit]
Description=My service
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
CPUAffinity=3
ExecStart=/path/to/startscript.sh
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

the startup script just makes sure the executable has executable rights, since there is a chance that after a manual update it has lost this.
And then executes it like so

```
nice -n -20 /path/to/exe.elf
```

The executable has a very high priority, it gets its own cpu and high niceness.

Comment: how is that service started? Could you share the .service file ?

Comment: I have added the service

Answer (score 1):

Why did you set `DefaultDependencies=no`? This is only needed in some unusual usecases.

The systemd.service(5) manpage says:

> Default Dependencies
> The following dependencies are added unless DefaultDependencies=no is set:
>
> •   Service units will have dependencies of type Requires= and After= on sysinit.target, a dependency of type After= on basic.target as well as dependencies of type Conflicts= and Before= on
> shutdown.target. These ensure that normal service units pull in basic system initialization, and are terminated cleanly prior to system shutdown. Only services involved with early boot or late
> system shutdown should disable this option.
>
> [...]

If you really need/want to set `DefaultDependencies=no`, you need to explicitly set the `After=/Before=/Conflicts=` dependencies manually, including against the `shutdown.target` target

Edit: BTW, you know that you have the `Nice=` property in the .service file? (see systemd.exec(5) manpage), no need of calling the `nice` executable

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I somehow have never spotted the `Nice=` property even though I've looked through the systemd man pages quite a lot. I will look into your comments about the `after/before/conflicts` properties